# Showing BootBox with button click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi I am a beginner and learning asp.net by myself. I want to show a confirmation dialog using bootbox. I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution for this. The bootbox documentation is also not precise really.

Here is the asp.net code for modal dialog:

```html
<!--BootBox Dialog -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        Are you Sure from master page?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer"><asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="okButton" Text="OK"/></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And by button:

```html
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="EditButton" CssClass="btn btn-primary"   ClientIDMode="Static">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Edit Selected
                            </asp:LinkButton>
```

The bootbox JavaScript to show confirm dialog:

```js
<script>
    $("#myModal").on("show", function() {    // wire up the OK button to dismiss the modal when shown
        $("#myModal a.btn").on("click", function(e) {
            console.log("button pressed");   // just as an example...
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');     // dismiss the dialog
        });
    });
    $("#myModal").on("hide", function() {    // remove the event listeners when the dialog is dismissed
        $("#myModal a.btn").off("click");
    });
    
    $("#myModal").on("hidden", function() {  // remove the actual elements from the DOM when fully hidden
        $("#myModal").remove();
    });
    
    $("#myModal").modal({                    // wire up the actual modal functionality and show the dialog
      "backdrop"  : "static",
      "keyboard"  : true,
      "show"      : true                     // ensure the modal is shown immediately
    });
</script>
```

Where should I pass the ID of the button and show the modal? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this--

```
$("#EditButton").on("click", function(){
```

//Do your Stuff here
}